# vi editor query

Tags: unix, shell, vi, ksh

I use vi quite often to edit files.
Usually I need the file to appear on screen with line numbers.
For this I do 
`set nu` in edit mode.
What a drag! Can I automate this? Is there any way where vi will directly open the file with line numbers visible immediately?
If so, are there any other tips that will make my experience with vi more efficient?

FYI, I don't have Vim.

Comment: Get vim.  It does everything vi does—and lots of things you wish vi did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://meiert.com/en/blog/20080525/tip-vi-config/

Enjoy. (Short version: make a text file called `.exrc` in your home directory and put vi commands there.)

Answer (score 2):

For folks that do have VIM - the related file is .vimrc - put commands in that.